# How can I ensure connections to office 365 are using tls1.2 only?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, tls

In attempting to tweak settings so that a computer and/or an application uses only tls1.2, I find myself relying on a Microsoft provided report that is not all that real-time.  The report I am pulling shows TLS1.0/1.1 and 3DES connections and is 2 or 3 days old each time I pull it.  It's in the "Service Trust Portal" and I navigate to it through the securescore.office.com website.

It doesn't specify what is being used, but rather if TLS1.0 or TLS1.1 or 3DES is being used (I think).  It only shows the protocol and doesn't specify if 3DES is being used, so it's of some help, but not absolutely the best.

So, is there any way within office 365 to determine what version of TLS is connecting in real-time (or at least kinda real-time) so that I know that an application is connecting using TLS1.2 and no other protocol?

Also, is there anyway to determine the cipher suite so that one could compare with acceptable cipher suites in order to be PCI or HIPAA compliant?

Thanks in advance.